# How to iterate over a list while applying a regex to it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to run this block of code.

```
castResultType = list(filterResultSet[1:32:5]) 
cleanList = []

for i in castResultType:
    cleanList.append(re.sub('[^\d\.]', '',castResultType[i]))

print(cleanList)
```

I'm hoping to get essentially each item in the list `castResultType`, which is getting specific values from the list `filterResultSet` inserted into the empty list `cleanList`. While also having the regex above applied to each value from `castResultType` before it's inserted into `cleanList`. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, and would appreciate any assistance. I'm also very new to python and programming in general, so I apologize if I'm asking something stupid.

Comment: do you get error message or wrong result? Show error and some data with expected result and what you get. I don't understand what is your problem

Comment: if `castResultType` is a list and you use `for i in castResultType:` then you have to use `i` instead of `castResultType[i]`. `for` gives you value from this list, not its index. `re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', i)`

Comment: @furas so I tried running this castResultType = list(filterResultSet[1:32:5]) 
cleanList = []

for i in castResultType:
    cleanList.append(re.sub('[^\d.]', '',i))

print(cleanList) but I got the error 'expected string or bytes-like object' and filterResultSet is a list of html tags with a data value enclosed between the two <td> tags. I'm trying to remove every character except the value from the tag.

Comment: @furas, I got it to work when I cast i as a str. I appreciate the insight that i is actually the value rather than the index.

Comment: better create minimal working code with some data - I don't know what is `filterResultSet` and how it work. If it is HTML tag then maybe you should first get value/text without tags - as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're (probably) facing is in this line: `for i in castResultType`.

What this line is doing is looping over the values within our `(list) castResultType` and assigning its elements to `i`. However, when you call `castResultType[i]`, you're asking for a non-existent index of the list.

What you probably meant to do is:

```py
for i in range(len(castResultType)):
    cleanList.append(re.sub('[^\d\.]', '',castResultType[i]))
# etc
```

What you could also do is:

```py
for i in castResultType:
   cleanList.append(re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', i))
# etc
```

There are a lot of other ways of coding what you want to do, but these are probably the most familiar for a beginner.

In addition to the bug in your looping, the problem could be in your use of regular expressions. I recommend experimenting with your regular expression on a single element from `castResultType` before looping through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `map` function to map a function to items in an iterable:

```
clean_list = list(map(lambda elem: re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', elem), castResultType))
```

Comment: Any idea how I can do this using the map function for clean_list again after the initial for loop rather than to do it for castResultType? For instance if I'm running two regex statements? I tried running clean_list = list(map(lambda elem: re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', elem), cleanList)) and it still returned non numeric values in the list. I also used a different sub initially on the first regex, that's why I ran with [^\d\.] again. I would be extremely grateful if you could provide some insight into this.

Comment: @randomguy2443 Are you trying to remove all non-numeric characters? If so you should be able to use `re.sub([^\d]*, '', elem)`. Either way you can define your own function `clean` that takes in a string and returns the cleaned version. Then replace the lambda function with `clean`. This is a straight forward way of applying multiple-functions to elements in an iterable.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for, and I learned something new. I really appreciate it. Upvoted you but doesn't show sadly because I have less than 15 points.